Stack 2d heatmaps on top of each to create 3d tomography plot in python
I am trying to understand how to create 3D tomography plots in python.  I have created a list of correlation matrices, and I want to plot each correlation matrix as a 2d heatmap, where the color represents the correlation value at that matrix indices.  Essentially, this amounts to stacking each 2d heatmap on top of one another, and creating a continuous color flow along the z-axis, where the z-axis is the date that each correlation matrix is measured at.  The color bar will be needed with this 3D tomography plot, to indicate the value of the correlation as a function of matrix indice and time.
The 2d heatmaps provided are each correlation matrix plotted as a 2d heatmap.  In general, I just want to rotate and angle each heatmap, and stack them on top of each other, to see how the colors of each matrix indice change along the vertical (time) axis.
A similar question has been asked (Python, Matplotlib: Stack multiple heatmaps on top of each other along z-axis in 3D), but this doesn't have the same data format.  The correlation matrices are an array, and each array needs to be plotted along the z-axis in this situation.
To achieve the above, the 2d heat map, itself, needs to be 3d.  Each square of the heatmap should actually be a cube in the heatmap array. The cubes then stacked on top of each other.  Is it possible to plot each matrix indice as a cube with the color of the cube set by the matrix indice value, and then have these cubes stacked on top of each other?





